# genstrings only finding 5 out of about 100 instances of NSLocalizedString

Tags: ios

I have about 100 instances where I'm using NSLocalizedString spread through multiple files in multiple directories.

I first tried to use this command from a high level directory to generate the .strings file:

```
find . -name \*.m | xargs genstrings -o en.lproj
```

But that resulted in the error:

```
couldn't connect to output directory en.lproj
```

So I just ran this:

```
find . -name \*.m | xargs genstrings
```

This generated a Localizable.strings file but the contents of it have only picked up NSLocalizedString occurrences from 2 files - which maybe not coincidentally happen to be in the same directory.

Why would the command only process one directory and then stop. I am running the command from a higher level directory H and these source files were found in M so the command found H/M but there are peer directories to M such as H/A H/B etc. containing .m files containing NSLocalizedString instances.

Any idea why the problem could be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think genstrings is breaking on folders that have names with spaces in them.  This worked for me:

```
find . -name "*.m" -print0 | xargs -0 genstrings -o "OUTPUT_FOLDER"
```

Answer (score 0):

I used cat to concatenate all the files into one, then ran genstrings on that to get.

Would be interested to know for curiosity why it didn't work without that however.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you have a directory called `en.lproj` in the directory where you are running the command from (presumably where the .xcodeproj lives). If it doesn't exist, simply create it.

Comment: That will solve the "couldn't connect to output directory" but the problem remains where only a very small number of instances of NSLocalizedString are being picked up from the source code.